# How to print according to number of objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I want to print number of objects according to this pattern:

```
If there is 1 object, print 0
If there is 2 objects, print 0 1
If there is 3 objects, print 0 1 2
```

I tried the following code:

```
for($i = count($nodes) ; $i >= 0 ; $i--){
print $i;
}
```

but the result is:

```
If there is 1 object, print 0 1
If there is 2 objects, print 0 1 2
if there is 3 objects, print 0 1 2 3
```

Which I can't use. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use like this:

```
 $n = 3; // where n is no. of object
for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
    print $i." ";
    }
 //output 0 1 2
```